# Scripting WINS Tombstone Removal

Tags: scripting, powershell, exchange-2007, wins, tombstones

I'm creating a script to remove the tombstoned entries in WINS (required for exchange w/ multi domains).  What I'd like to know is if removing those old entries will break anything?  Or if there's anything I should look out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it should not break anything.  Tombstoned records in WINS aren't used anyway. According to TechNet:

> ... The owning WINS server changes the status of selected WINS records
>   from active to tombstoned in its database. WINS then treats the
>   records as inactive and released from use. **Once these records are
>   tombstoned locally, the owning WINS server neither responds to nor
>   resolves NetBIOS name queries for these names from other WINS clients
>   and WINS servers unless the records are registered again by the WINS
>   client.** The owning WINS server replicates the selected records as
>   "tombstoned" to other WINS servers during subsequent replication
>   cycles.